# Сортировка tr по значению td

Tags: javascript

Не могу поменять `tr` местами, тестирую на индексированном массиве, все получается заменять местами, а вот со строками таблицы не могу понять как

[код на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9fj9zf2j/2/)

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td class="px">4</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="px">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="px">2</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="px">3</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('px');

for(i=0, len=list.length-1; i<len; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<len; j++) {
        let this_val = list[i].innerHTML; // текущее значение
        let next_val = list[i+1].innerHTML; // следующее значение

        let this_parent = list[i].parentNode; // текущй родитель (tr)
        let next_parent = list[i+1].parentNode; // следующий родитель (tr)

        let tbody = this_parent.parentNode; // tbody

        if(this_val > next_val) {
            // next_parent поставить перед this_parent
            tbody.insertBefore(next_parent, tbody[this_parent.sectionRowIndex]);
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно отсортировать `tr` местами, по значению `td`.
То есть чтобы было

```html
<tr><td class="px">1</td></tr>
<tr><td class="px">2</td></tr> 
<tr><td class="px">3</td></tr>
<tr><td class="px">4</td></tr>
```

А сейчас

```html
<tr><td class="px">4</td></tr>
<tr><td class="px">1</td></tr> 
<tr><td class="px">2</td></tr>
<tr><td class="px">3</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Непонятно зачем нужна строка

```
tbody[this_parent.sectionRowIndex]
```

если достаточно

```
this_parent
```

```js
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('px');

for (var i = 0, len = list.length - 1; i < len; i++) {

  for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
    let this_val = list[i].innerHTML;
    let next_val = list[i + 1].innerHTML;

    let this_parent = list[i].parentNode;
    let next_parent = list[i + 1].parentNode;

    let tbody = this_parent.parentNode;

    if (this_val > next_val) {
      // next_parent поставить перед this_parent
      tbody.insertBefore(next_parent, this_parent);
    }

  }

}
```

```html
<div id="res"></div>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="px">4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="px">1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="px">2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="px">3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```